# Sickness occurrence distribution among populations and poisson random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

The number of times someone gets sick in a year  is given by a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda = 5$. Let us suppose there is a new medicine which reduces the parameter lambda to $\lambda = 3$ for $75\%$ of the population. For the remaining $25\%$, the drug has no effect. If a person takes the medicine for a whole year and gets sick twice, what is the probability that the drug is effective to him?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let us divide the population into two parts according to the parameter lambda: $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$. Moreover, let us also denote by $N$ the number of times the person has got sick in the year. Therefore we are interested in the probability:

\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(P_{1}\mid N = 2) = \frac{\textbf{P}(P_{1}\cap\{N = 2\})}{\textbf{P}(N = 2)} = \frac{\textbf{P}(N = 2\mid P_{1})\textbf{P}(P_{1})}{\textbf{P}(N = 2\mid P_{1})\textbf{P}(P_{1}) + \textbf{P}(N = 2\mid P_{2})\textbf{P}(P_{2})}
\end{align*}

where

\begin{cases}
\textbf{P}(P_{1}) = 0.75\\\\
\textbf{P}(P_{2}) = 0.25\\\\
\textbf{P}(N = 2\mid P_{1}) = \displaystyle\frac{e^{-3}\times 3^{2}}{2!}\\\\
\textbf{P}(N = 2\mid P_{2}) = \displaystyle\frac{e^{-5}\times 5^{2}}{2!}
\end{cases}

I just would like that someone could double-check my solution and correct it if necessary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't answered the final question.

Comment: Unlesss I am distracted, the answer is given by $\textbf{P}(P_{1}\mid N = 2)$, whose expression I have determined. I was just wondering if my reasoning is right. Anyway, I apologize if this is not the case.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.  I missed the fact that you had stated it at the beginning, since you didn't put it all together at the end.

Comment: No problems. Thanks for the contribution, anyway.